mining-setup vs miner-configuration vs mining-software
What is the best tag to describe the questions dealing with the configuration and software of miners? Should this tag also collect building your own miners (although this is mostly a historical topic)?
We currently have:

mining-setup
[Mining-Setup] is used for questions concerned with the setup and configuration of mining hardware.
miner-configuration
Collects questions about configuration of mining hardware, and optimizing the software settings of mining rigs.
mining-software
No description yet.

